# Basic Auth to a webpack build

Tags: reactjs, webpack, basic-authentication

I'm using the ant design library for React. I've created a `.webpackrc.js` file as seen below.

```
const path = require('path');
export default {
  entry: 'src/index.js',
  extraBabelPlugins: [['import', { libraryName: 'antd', libraryDirectory: 'es', style: true }]],
  env: {
    development: {
      extraBabelPlugins: ['dva-hmr'],
    },
  },
  externals: {
    '@antv/data-set': 'DataSet',
  },
  alias: {
    components: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/components/'),
  },
  ignoreMomentLocale: true,
  theme: './src/theme.js',
  html: {
    template: './src/index.ejs',
  },
  lessLoaderOptions: {
    javascriptEnabled: true,
  },
  disableDynamicImport: true,
  publicPath: '/',
  hash: true,
};
```

I'm trying to add http basic auth to the webpack server which prompts users for a username and password. I've seen some examples with `webpack.config.js`, but not with `.webpackrc.js`. New to webpack so any examples would be appreciated.